# How to use ng-content inside router outlet view?

Tags: angular

My root component is like

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In router outlet as usual i am rendering different components for different routes.But in all the components which is rendered by router outlet i want to place a footer `app-footer`. So if all the child components if i mark a place for content injection by `ng-content` and then use `<router-outlet><app-footer></app-footer></router-outlet>` my footer is placed in the wrong place. After some time i realized that my child components aren't rendered inside the `router-outlet` but like

```
<router-outlet _ng-content -cux-98></router-outlet>
<app-child-component></app-child-component>
```

If i write my root component html like

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

than my footer is below the child component not inside the child component like

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-child-component></app-child-component>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

so how can i place my footer inside of the child component using router-outlet. I know that i manually can place that inside all of the child components directly but i want to place it from my root component so that footer code doesn't need to download on every child component's loading. How can i achieve this?